# Facebook page wall autopost picture resize

Tags: php, html, css, facebook

I have successfully created code for posting my website inputs to Facebook page using long lived access token.

SDK used: PHP SDK v5

**Problem**

1) Picture not displaying despite I am sharing absolute path.

2) Picture area posted using following code, showing full width. Is there any way to resize like expected result image.

[image]

**My code**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

require_once 'facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';
//facebook page id
$pageId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

//LONG LIVED ACCESS TOKEN (60 DAYS)
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

if (isset($token)) 
{
    $client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    try 
    {
      $accessToken = $client->getLongLivedAccessToken($token);
    } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }


    $response = $fb->get('/me/accounts', (string) $token);

    foreach ($response->getDecodedBody() as $allPages) 
    {
        foreach ($allPages as $page ) 
        {               

            if (isset($page['id']) && $page['id'] == $pageId) 
            { // Suppose you save it as this variable
                $appAccessToken = (string) $page['access_token'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $response = $fb->post(
        '/'.$pageId.'/feed',
        array(
            "message" => "http://www.aazabc.com/30",
            "link" => "http://www.aazabc.com/30",
            "picture" => "http://www.aazabc.com/images/jobs.jpg",
            "name" => "UK SHIFT INBOUND CUSTOMER SERVICE / BOTH SIDE CABS",
            "caption" => "www.aazabc.com",
            "description" => "Hiring For UK Telecom Customer Service Process Inbound Customer Service UG / Grad / Dropout CAN Apply Freshers Can Apply 5 Days Working Location Gurgaon International Training Facility Both Side Cab Salary 20K - 25K + Incentives (8K-10K)"
        ),
        $appAccessToken
    );

    // Success
    $postId = $response->getGraphNode();
//    echo $postId;

}
```

**Expected result (if possible)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When I try to go to the picture url you provided, I get an 404 error: the image can't be found. So that's why is isn't loaded.
2. Your desired result is sort of deprecated. [Facebook wants the image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) to be at least 200x200 pixels, but the bigger the image (in a certain aspect ratio) the better:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on
>   high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that
>   are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>   Images can be up to 8MB in size.

Also make sure to use `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` to let Facebook already know what the actual image size is.

**Tip:** Please use the [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to try and correct your errors.